# why add curly braces to the argument 'people' here

Tags: reactjs

```
 const List = ({people}) => {
    return (
     <>
     {people.map(person =>{
       const {id,name,age,image} = person;
        return (
          <article key={id} className='person'>
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
            <div>
              <h4>{name}</h4>
              <p>{age} years</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      })}
    </>
    );
  };
```

Comment: See: [MDN - Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: `props` destructuring.. Duplicated from above